# Android : how to add an url image to my header in iText generated PDF

Tags: android, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I'm using iText to generate a PDF.Pdf is generated for showing some records in a school, so I need to show a school Emblem and school name at the center of the top header of the first page. I have the string HTTP URL of the image file which may be of any size. I want to resize the image without losing its quality and adjust it at the header portion(so it make sense) and need to show the school name below. My problem is I don't know how to add the image so it is displayed in the "header box".

Here there are some code snippets ...

```
private void createPdf() {
    try {
        String imgURL = "http URL";
        String schoolName = "School Name";
        File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "PROJECT");
        if (! filePath.exists()){
            if (! filePath.mkdirs()){

            }else{

            }
        }
        // Create a file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        fileExp = new File(filePath+"/Report_"+ timeStamp + ".pdf");
        photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", fileExp);
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(fileExp));
        document.open();
        addMetaData(document);
        
        Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
        // We add one empty line
        addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
        // Lets write a big header
        Paragraph para1 = new Paragraph(repHeader, catFont);
        para1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        preface.add(para1);
        addEmptyLine(preface, 2);

        Paragraph para3 = new Paragraph("Period : ", textBold);
        Chunk perChunk3 = new Chunk("from  "+edtFromDate.getText().toString()+"  to  "+edtToDate.getText().toString(),textNormal);
        para3.add(perChunk3);
        preface.add(para3);
        addEmptyLine(preface, 1);

        document.close();
        //insertDocument("Report_"+ timeStamp + ".pdf");
        Intent emailIn = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIn.setType("application/pdf");
        emailIn.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoURI);
        emailIn.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        emailIn.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { selEmailId });
        emailIn.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Report : "+repHeader);
        emailIn.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, repHeader);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIn, "E-mail"),15);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Below is the dependency :

```
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an image to the document and scale as the image by preferred height or width using the below code

Here I have scaled the image width according to the `preferredImageHeight`

```java
Image image = Image.getInstance("https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/rickandmorty/images/9/95/HarryherpsonHS.jpg/revision/latest/top-crop/width/360/height/360?cb=20150908094923");
image.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
System.out.println("Image width: " + image.getScaledWidth() + ", height: " + image.getScaledHeight());
float preferredImageHeight = 60;
float widthScale = image.getScaledHeight() / preferredImageHeight;
image.scaleAbsolute(image.getScaledWidth() / widthScale, preferredImageHeight);
System.out.println("Image width: " + image.getScaledWidth() + ", height: " + image.getScaledHeight());
document.add(image);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would follow the instructions here https://memorynotfound.com/adding-header-footer-pdf-using-itext-java/ and customise their code to suit.

for the purposes of keeping answers here, the basic is that you need to create an "addHeader" method just before your document.close()

using something similar to this code block

```
 private void addHeader(PdfWriter writer){
    PdfPTable header = new PdfPTable(2);
    try {
        // set defaults
        header.setWidths(new int[]{2, 24});
        header.setTotalWidth(527);
        header.setLockedWidth(true);
        header.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(40);
        header.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
        header.getDefaultCell().setBorderColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);

        // add image
        Image logo = Image.getInstance(HeaderFooterPageEvent.class.getResource("/memorynotfound-logo.jpg"));
        header.addCell(logo);

        // add text
        PdfPCell text = new PdfPCell();
        text.setPaddingBottom(15);
        text.setPaddingLeft(10);
        text.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
        text.setBorderColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
        text.addElement(new Phrase("iText PDF Header Footer Example", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12)));
        text.addElement(new Phrase("https://memorynotfound.com", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8)));
        header.addCell(text);

        // write content
        header.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 34, 803, writer.getDirectContent());
    } catch(DocumentException de) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
    }
}
```